# Why is this compass considerably off?

Tags: google-earth

Here is a Google Earth screenshot of “Edwards AFB” in California:
[image]

-The green circle has the compass in it...

Here’s a zoomed in screenshot of the compass:
[image]

Notice how my Google Earth compass (in green again) is pointing directly North but the compass in the picture *isn’t very close to pointing North compared to the other one*

If I had to guess which compass is off, I would say it’s Google’s, but why wouldn’t the compasses be closer than this?

Comment: And if you folks want to give me feedback that would be nice too, I’m new to this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Earth's compass points towards the *[geographic North Pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Pole)*, while airplanes traditionnally work with magnetic compasses, hence all compasses and airstrip numbers are relative to the Earth's [North Magnetic Pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Magnetic_Pole) (they use the magnetic field). The compass that you see in the sand at Edwards AFB is a magnetic compass, pointing towards the North Magnetic Pole, and is offset by around 15° from geographic bearings. The difference between the two is call the *[magnetic declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination)*.

Answer (score 1):

While the main reason is that Google Earth uses true north and the compass rose is magnetic north, that does not explain everything.  It is still off.  This is because it was drawn a long time ago, and they do not update it, even when they re-stripe it.  It is now off by "Several Degrees".

If you look at old images on Google Earth Pro you will see that it never changes.
I measure it as 15.26 degress off of true north on Google Earth.  NOAA says it is currently 11 degrees 37 minutes off.

See the following article from Edwards:
https://www.edwards.af.mil/News/Article/828690/can-you-see-me-now-lakebeds-restriped/